Alternative to call another async function inside 2 forEach loops
I'm trying to call a function inside a forEach loop, which is inside another forEach loop, but it doesn't return/invoke the function.
I have looked at this question but as I'm still a novice I cant seem to make it work.
This is my code (it returns password credentials for each service principle in azure, then checks the expiry date and outputs based on the difference of that date and the day of the run). I want to fire an API call to JIRA to create a ticket if it falls within the first 2 if conditions.
const execute = async () => {
  allAdApps = await exec('az ad app list --all');
  const allAdAppsJson = JSON.parse(allAdApps);

  const servicePrinciples = allAdAppsJson.filter((app) => app.displayName);
  servicePrinciples.forEach((sp) => {
    sp.passwordCredentials.forEach((passwordCred) => {
      const formatExpiryDate = new Date(passwordCred.endDateTime);
      const diffInTime = formatExpiryDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
      const diffInDays = Math.floor(diffInTime / msInOneDay);

      if (diffInDays <= 30 && diffInDays > 0) {
        const logStr2 = `${sp.displayName}' will expire in '${diffInDays}' days.`;
        logger.info(logStr2);
        // my function call here
        const output = jiraCheckDuplicate('Ticket title');
      } else if (diffInDays < 0) {
        const expStr = `'${sp.displayName}' already expired '${diffInDays}' days ago.`;
        logger.info(expStr);
        // my function call here
        const output = jiraCheckDuplicate('Ticket title');
      } else {
        logger.info('string');
      }
    });
  });

};

execute()
  .then(() => process.exit())
  .catch((err) => {
    logger.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  });

I have tried to change the forEach to a for of, but still getting no response from my function
const execute = async () => {
  allAdApps = await exec('az ad app list --all');
  const allAdAppsJson = JSON.parse(allAdApps);

  const servicePrinciples = allAdAppsJson.filter((app) => app.displayName);
  for (const sp of servicePrinciples) {
    for (const passwordCred of sp.passwordCredentials) {
      const formatExpiryDate = new Date(passwordCred.endDateTime);
      const diffInTime = formatExpiryDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
      const diffInDays = Math.floor(diffInTime / msInOneDay);

      if (diffInDays <= 30 && diffInDays > 0) {
        const logStr2 = `${sp.displayName}' will expire in '${diffInDays}' days.`;
        logger.info(logStr2);
        // my function call here
        await jiraCheckDuplicate('Ticket title', user, token);
      } else if (diffInDays < 0) {
        const expStr = `'${sp.displayName}' already expired '${diffInDays}' days ago.`;
        logger.info(expStr);
        // my function call here
        await jiraCheckDuplicate('Ticket title', user, token);
      } else {
        logger.info('string');
      }
    }
  }
};

execute()
  .then(() => process.exit())
  .catch((err) => {
    logger.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  });

I've tried using .map and promises, but again to no avail. (See this question)
const execute = async () => {
  allAdApps = await exec('az ad app list --all');
  const allAdAppsJson = JSON.parse(allAdApps);

  const servicePrinciples = allAdAppsJson.filter((app) => app.displayName);
  const promises2 = servicePrinciples.map(async (sp) => {
    const promises = sp.passwordCredentials.map(async (passwordCred) => {
      const formatExpiryDate = new Date(passwordCred.endDateTime);
      const diffInTime = formatExpiryDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
      const diffInDays = Math.floor(diffInTime / msInOneDay);

      if (diffInDays <= 30 && diffInDays > 0) {
        const logStr2 = `${sp.displayName}' will expire in '${diffInDays}' days.`;
        logger.info(logStr2);
        // my function call here
        await jiraCheckDuplicate('Ticket title', user, token).promise();
      } else if (diffInDays < 0) {
        const expStr = `'${sp.displayName}' already expired '${diffInDays}' days ago.`;
        logger.info(expStr);
        // my function call here
        await jiraCheckDuplicate('Ticket title', user, token).promise();
      } else {
        logger.info(logStr);
      }
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);
  });
};

execute()
  .then(() => process.exit())
  .catch((err) => {
    logger.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  });




I've simplified my function to a 'hello world' output to eliminate any possible error in the cURL request - the function does work when calling outside the for loops
const jiraCheckDuplicate = async (
  summary,
  user,
  token,
) => {
  const auth = `${user}:${token}`;

  const urlSummary = encodeURIComponent(summary);

  fetch(`https://enterprisevm.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=summary~%22'${urlSummary}'%22+and+status!="Done"`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(
        auth,
      ).toString('base64')}`,
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      logger.info(
        `Response: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`,
      );
      return response.text();
    })
    .then((text) => logger.info(text))
    .catch((err) => logger.error(err));
};

module.exports = jiraCheckDuplicate;


forEach() expects a synchronous function — it does not wait for promises. Make sure you are aware of the implications while using promises (or async functions) as forEach callbacks. Try changing that servicePrinciples.forEach with a regular for statement and possibly any other similar thing.

I have tried a regular for and also used map but neither are working

JiraCheckDuplicate doesn’t return anything. return fetch(…)

Your middle snippet (with the for … of) should work. What exactly do you mean by "still getting no response from my function", what response did you expect and what did you see instead (did it just hang? exit early?)? What is jiraCheckDuplicate doing, have you confirmed that it does work on its own?

Your last snippet is missing an await Promise.all(promises2) at the last line of the execute funciton

@Bergi jiraCheckDuplicate performs a search on our JIRA instance for any tickets matching the summary sent in. When I call it from the top of the execute function it returns with any ticket details it finds. When it's in the for loop, there is no output (not even console log with 'hello world'). It doesn't hang, the full process completes just with no output from that function

So maybe servicePrinciples or passwordCredentials are empty arrays?

await Promise.all(promises2) added, still nothing output

servicePrinciples or passwordCredentials are not empty, there is other output containing the details of their expiries

Oh wait, the problem is indeed in the jiraCheckDuplicate code, I completely missed that in the post. As @James already says, it does not return anything and doesn't await anything either! You immediately call process.exit() after starting the requests. Fix that, and then also drop the unnecessary .then(() => process.exit()).

Ultimately, it came down to using:
for (const sp of servicePrinciples) {
    for (const passwordCred of sp.passwordCredentials) {

removing process.exit() and updating jiraCheckDuplicate to be an async function with return:
const jiraCheckDuplicate = async (


To credit users who commented on your question and helped, [edit] your question to add something like this: [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79001823/alternative-to-call-another-async-function-inside-2-foreach-loops/79006748#comment139298962_79001823): >[their comment], and so on. This ensures proper attribution and avoids chatty terms, which are not suitable for Stack Overflow, just like they aren't on Wikipedia. To get the comment link, left-click on the timestamp. Hope this helps, and good luck.
